If conditional does not work inside a pymodbus async python program why is this happening?
I'm using a python program to communicate with a PLC using OPCUA as well as a mass flow controller to dose some substances, using modbus.
async def read_input_registers(modbusclient, start_address, num_elements, slave, datatype):
    response = await modbusclient.read_input_registers(start_address, num_elements, unit=slave)
    if response.isError():
        logging.error(f"Read Input Registers Error for {datatype}: {response}")
    else:
        if datatype == 'B':
            data = response.registers[0]
        else:
            data_bytes = b''.join(pack('>H', register) for register in response.registers)
            data = unpack(datatype, data_bytes)
        print(f"{datatype} Data:", data)
    return data


This is the function i use to read from the modbus registers and the following is where I use this function
MFC_01DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
await record_variables('MFC01_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)

MFC_02DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
await record_variables('MFC02_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedQuantity_g)

MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)

MFC_02DosingStatus = await read_input_registers(11, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
await record_variables('MFC02_DosingStatus', MFC_02DosingStatus)

status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')

    if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512 or MFC_02DosingStatus == 512:
        print(f"Error detected at stage {status}, shutting down...")
        sys.exit()

My problem is that my if condition does not seem to work. The code always goes to sys.exit() despite the value of MFC_01DosingStatus and MFC_02DosingStatus being 256.
I've tried to check for a type mismatch, they seem like integers. The record_variables function records them into a .csv file as integers. I'm not sure what else to try.
This is the full function along with what is actually run during the program.
import asyncio
import logging
import serial
from asyncua import Client, ua
from pymodbus.client import AsyncModbusTcpClient
from struct import pack, unpack
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys

async def PhosDCI_operations(modbusclient, MFC01_R1Quantity_g,
                             MFC02_R2Quantity_g,
                             R1_VP,
                             R2_VP,
                             MFC02_R3Quantity_g,
                             R3_VP,
                             MFC02_R4Quantity_g,
                             R4_VP,
                             client
                             ):
   await modbusclient.connect()
   stop_event = asyncio.Event()
   try:
       # Since the Modbus operations are synchronous, run them in executor to avoid blocking the event loop
       loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
   
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R1_VP, 1)
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R2_VP, 1)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.BB_1", True)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBVesselGasRelief", True) # Write for the HMI valve opening for DCI
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
       # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_01&02
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, MFC01_R1Quantity_g/5/1000, 1) #MFC01_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 2711, MFC02_R2Quantity_g/5/1000, 1) #MFC02_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test.
       # Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       MFC_01DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_02DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       MFC_02DosingStatus = await read_input_registers(11, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosingStatus', MFC_02DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512 or MFC_02DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
         
       # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_01&02
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test.
       MFC_01DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_02DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       MFC_02DosingStatus = await read_input_registers(11, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosingStatus', MFC_02DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512 or MFC_02DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test.
       # Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       MFC_01DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_02DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       MFC_02DosingStatus = await read_input_registers(11, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosingStatus', MFC_02DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512 or MFC_02DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test.
       MFC_01DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_02DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       MFC_02DosingStatus = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 11, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosingStatus', MFC_02DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512 or MFC_02DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test.
       # Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       MFC_01DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_02DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       MFC_02DosingStatus = await read_input_registers(11, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosingStatus', MFC_02DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512 or MFC_02DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R1_VP, 0)
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R2_VP, 0)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.BB_1", False)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBVesselGasRelief", False) 
       
       # Washing step
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, 25/1000, 1) #MFC01_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 2711, 25/1000, 1) #MFC02_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 1, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       
       # Coupling Time
       await asyncio.sleep(1200)
       MFC_01WashQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_WashQuantity_g', MFC_01WashQuantity_g)
       MFC_02WashQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_WashQuantity_g', MFC_02WashQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       MFC_02DosingStatus = await read_input_registers(11, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosingStatus', MFC_02DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512 or MFC_02DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Oligo Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()

       ## Cyanethanol
       # Write the code to take Cyanethanol_VP
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R3_VP, 1)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.R3", True)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBVesselGasRelief", True) 
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
       # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_02
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, MFC02_R3Quantity_g/1000, 1) #MFC01_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       # Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(20) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R3_VP, 0)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.R3", False)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBVesselGasRelief", False) # Write for the HMI valve opening for DCI
       MFC_02DosedR3Quantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_R3Quantity_g', MFC_02DosedR3Quantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Oligo Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       
       # Washing Step
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, 25/1000, 1) #MFC01_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       
       # Quench Time
       #await asyncio.sleep(300)
       await asyncio.sleep(300)
       MFC_01WashQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_WashQuantity_g', MFC_01WashQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       
       ## POS_CSO
       # write the code to take PSOCSO_VP in 3 batches
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R4_VP_VP, 1)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.R4", True)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBVesselGasRelief", True) #
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
        # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_02
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, MFC02_R4Quantity_g/5/1000, 1) #MFC02_SetpointDosingQuantity
       # 1st Batch - Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_POSCSOQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       

       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_POSCSOQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.OligoStage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()

       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       MFC_01DosedCSOQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_POSCSOQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedCSOQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_POSCSOQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(100) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_POSCSOQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedR4Quantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()

       await asyncio.sleep(0.1) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, R4_VP, 0)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.R4", False)
       await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBVesselGasRelief", False) # Write for the HMI valve opening for DCI
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       
       # Washing step
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, 25/1000, 1) #MFC02_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       
       # POS_CSO time
       await asyncio.sleep(3600)
       MFC_01WashQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_WashQuantity_g', MFC_01WashQuantity_g)
       MFC_01DosingStatus =  await read_input_registers(modbusclient,1, 1, 1, 'B')  # Unsigned8 datatype
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosingStatus', MFC_01DosingStatus)
       status = await read_input_value(client, 'ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Stage')
       if MFC_01DosingStatus == 512:
           print(f"Dosing Error detected at Oligo Stage {status}, shutting down...")
           sys.exit()
       
     
       
   finally:
       # stop_event.set()
       await asyncio.sleep(1) #Disconnect - estimate how long the dosing will take
    #    await keep_alive_task
       modbusclient.close()
 
       for i in range(16):
        set_valve_position(i, 0)


async def main():
   url = "opc.tcp://169.254.232.191:4840"
   logging.info(f"Connecting to {url} ...")
   # Modbus TCP client initialization
   modbusclient = AsyncModbusTcpClient('192.168.0.100', timeout=6000)
   async with Client(url=url) as client:
       root = client.get_root_node()
       logging.info(f"Objects root node is: {root}")
       coupling_param = {
                          1.5: (52.64, 51.50, 6, 8, 2.92, 2, 153.25, 5), #mG(ibu)
                          2.5: (59.20, 51.50, 7, 8, 2.92, 2, 153.25, 5), #mU(Bz)
                          3.5: (59.20, 51.50, 7, 8, 2.92, 2, 153.25, 5), #mU(Bz)
                          4.5: (59.20, 51.50, 7, 8, 2.92, 2, 153.25, 5), #mU(Bz)
                          5.5: (59.20, 51.50, 7, 8, 2.92, 2, 153.25, 5), #mU(Bz)
                          6.5: (82.74, 51.50, 1, 8, 2.92, 2, 153.25, 5), #mc(Ac)
                          7.5: (52.64, 51.50, 6, 8, 2.92, 2, 153.25, 5) #mG(ibu)
                          } #PhosDCI_operations(MFC01_PhosphoramiditeQuantity_g, MFC02_DCIQuantity_g, Phosphoramiditie_VP, DCI_VP, MFC02_CyanethanolQuantity_g, Cyanethanol_VP, MFC02_POSCSOQuantity_g, POSCSO_VP)
       detrit_param = {
                         1: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800),
                         2: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800),
                         3: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800),
                         4: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800),
                         5: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800),
                         6: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800),
                         7: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800),
                         8: (48.39, 8.88, 62.21, 10, 3, 9, 1800)
                         } #Detrit_operations(MFC02_TFAQuantity_g, MFC02_TEMESQuantity_g, MFC02_PicolineQuantity_g, TFA_VP, TEMES_VP, Picoline_VP, client)
       while True:
            ## Should replace the node_value woth a 'handshake' value from PLC
            ## One node_value for coupling (potentially sub divided into phos-DCI, quench, PO/PS0)
            ## Onde node_value for detrit (potentially sub divided into traps and then acid)
            node_value = await read_input_value(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing")
            process_stage = await read_input_value(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.ProcessStage") ## Assign Process_stage to GVL.ProcessStage
            if node_value:
                logging.info(f"Node value: {node_value}")
                if process_stage == int(process_stage):
                    #await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing", True)
               
                    await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Detritylation", True)  # Writing an integer value
               
                   
               
                    await Detrit_operations(modbusclient, *detrit_param[process_stage], client)
               
 
               
                    await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing", False)  # Writing an integer value
               
 
               
                    await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBDFMode", True)  # Writing an integer value
                   
 
                else:
               
                    await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Coupling", True)  # Writing an integer value
 
           
                    await PhosDCI_operations(modbusclient, *coupling_param[process_stage], client)
 
               
                    await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing", False)  # Writing an integer value
 
               
                    await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBDFMode", True)  # Writing an integer value
                   
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
            else:
                logging.info("Node value is not True, skipping Modbus operations")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)  # Adjust sleep duration as needed
if __name__ == "__main__":
   asyncio.run(main())


please, postat least the full function (including declaration, and correct indentation) with the code that is aborted with the sys.exit call.

thank you for the complete function: the if guards are all correct, and there is not a chance something that fundamental would not work in Python, nor any other published language. On the other hand, you never print the values actually checked in the if statements when exiting: try just adding these extra prints, and you will find-out which values are actually reading as 512 (because if os.exi()t is being reached, that is actually happening)

Thank you for your response, using the record_variable function, i write the DosingStatus values to a CSV. Additionally, the read_input_registers function prints the values too so I check them in terminal output. What ends up happening is that despite the both the values being 256, the program exits.

Don't know the library, but is MFC_02DosingStatus an int? If it some special UINT8 object, then in 8 bits both 256 and 512 are the same (zero, overflowed).

You can replace the "sys.exit()calls withraise SystemExit(): this will keep the termination semantics (if that is really what you want, but I'd recomend you to get some Python consulting with this code, paid for, if needed)  - Anyway, raising an exception allows you to run the code with python -m pdb` and you will get an interactive debugger prompt at the point the exception is raised - allowing you to inspect the variables, and assert what is happening that was not planned.
